# PHP - Regex to get integer value that formatted separated by character

Tags: php, regex

If I have a string like this :

```
TAX ID NO. 01.000.589.0.055.000
```

My goal is, I want to get the integer digit after `tax` phrase, which is `010005890055000`

So far I write like this

```
/(tax id no)\s*[^A-Za-z0-9]?\s*\K\d+/i
```

but It still not true because sometimes user wrote like this:

```
TAX ID. 01.000.589.0.055.000 or
TAX ID : 01.000.589.0.055.000 or
TAX ID 01.000.589.0.055.000 or
TAX: 01.000.589.0.055.000
```

even user wrote directly into a prefect integer digit

```
TAX ID NO. 010005890055000
```

Please advise

This is all my possibilities:

1. Non Formatted

   JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID NO. 010005890055000
2. Formatted

   JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID NO. 01.000.589.0.055.000
3. With different `tax` phrase

   JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX 010005890055000

   JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID 01.000.589.0.055.000

   JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID. 010005890055000
4. In beginning a sentence

   TAX ID. 010005890055000 , JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA

   TAX ID. 01.000.589.0.055.000 , JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA

So much thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your only consistent keyword is `TAX`, so you can grab digits (with dots and dashes) after it with the regex `~TAX.*?\.? *?([\d\.-]+)~i`, then strip non-digits (if desired). Here's an example test:

```
$data = "JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID NO. 010005890055000
JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID NO. 01.000.589.0.055.000
JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX 010005890055000
JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID 01.000.589.0.055.000
JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID. 010005890055000
TAX ID. 010005890055000 , JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA
tax ID. 01.000.589.0.055.000 , JL
TAX ID. 01.000.589.0.055.000 , JL. CACING RT 007/008 CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA
JL. CAKUNG CILINCING KP BARU RT 007/008 CAKUNG BARAT, CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID NO. 01.109.421.6-902.000";

foreach (explode("\n", $data) as $line) {
    preg_match("~TAX.*?\.? *?([\d\.-]+)~i", $line, $m);
    echo preg_replace("~\D~", "", $m[1]) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
010005890055000
010005890055000
010005890055000
010005890055000
010005890055000
010005890055000
010005890055000
010005890055000
011094216902000
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/RadiantHummingTrigger)

Comment: Sorry, it is not in a line.

Comment: OK, this is just an example. `preg_replace("~\D~", "", $line)` works on all of your test cases regardless of whether they're individual strings or not. If not, let me know what sort of input you are dealing with that isn't working and I'll update.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but how with formatted number as explained above ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. Your expected output is `010005890055000` and this is what this emits.

Comment: Sorry, it for example, people can write like this JL. CAKUNG CILINCING KP BARU RT 007/008 CAKUNG BARAT, CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID NO. 01.109.421.6-902.000

Comment: Can you list all of your possible input cases in the question from the beginning? It's not helpful for you or us to continually adjust the requirements.

Comment: This handles all of your tests.

Comment: Oke, So much thank you, i dont see the preg_replace after preg_match. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: and also for the tax in lowercase, i still struggle to preg_match them like ~TAX.*?\.? *?([\d\.-]+)+/i~

Comment: Put the `i` after the end delimiter `~`. See update.

Comment: Working as charm, thanks.
Sorry if I asked not clearly.Basically from my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of this:

`/(?:tax\s*(?:id\s*)?).*?(\d[\d\.]+)/i`

The first group checks for `tax` with `id` being optional. It then grabs the first digit and all digit and `.` and groups it under `$1`

[**Regexr**](https://regexr.com/43e69)

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_replace to remove all but numbers.

```
preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str);
```

see output: https://3v4l.org/Ne3fo

---

To answer the new requirement:
Use substr and strpos to remove the part up to "tax".

```
$arr = ["TAX ID. 01.000.589.0.055.000 or",
"TAX ID : 01.000.589.0.055.000 or",
"TAX ID 01.000.589.0.055.000 or",
"TAX: 01.000.589.0.055.000",
"ARU RT 007/008 CAKUNG BARAT, CAKUNG, JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID NO. 010005890055000"];

foreach($arr as $str){
    echo preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', substr($str, stripos($str, "tax"))) . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/btDAq

Comment: Sorry, basically its part of long string, ex "JAKARTA TIMUR 13910 INDONESIA TAX ID 01.328.570.5-007.000"

Comment: in that case the output becomes 13910013285705007000. Keep in mind what your question says.

Comment: Clearly after 'tax' phrase. Thanks

Comment: *If I have a string like this :* and *but It still not true because sometimes user wrote like this:*. Nothing is clear unless you make it clear!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex, where except TAX part, I have made everything that comes in middle between tax and numbers as optional. Use this regex and capture group1

```
/tax(?:.*?)\s+([\d.]+)/i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U8iZC1/1)

Once you get digit and dot part, remove all dot characters from it.

Here is a sample php code,

```
$arr = ["TAX ID NO. 01.000.589.0.055.000","TAX ID. 01.000.589.0.055.000","TAX ID : 01.000.589.0.055.000","TAX ID 01.000.589.0.055.000","TAX: 01.000.589.0.055.000", "TAX ID NO. 010005890055000"];

foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    preg_match('/tax(?:.*?)\s+([\d.]+)/i', $value, $matches);
    echo $value . " --> " . preg_replace('/\./','',$matches[1]) . "\n";
}
```

This prints following output,

```
TAX ID NO. 01.000.589.0.055.000 --> 010005890055000
TAX ID. 01.000.589.0.055.000 --> 010005890055000
TAX ID : 01.000.589.0.055.000 --> 010005890055000
TAX ID 01.000.589.0.055.000 --> 010005890055000
TAX: 01.000.589.0.055.000 --> 010005890055000
TAX ID NO. 010005890055000 --> 010005890055000
```

Comment: I believe this one could work even with the new string